# CentOS 6.5 SVN https - Unknown DAV provider: svn

Tags: svn, httpd, mod-dav-svn

I am trying to setup a CentOS 6.5 64bit server with SVN over HTTPS. Unfortunately after configuring the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf` file as follows (changed paths):

```
<Location /repos>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /path/to/svn/repos

    # Limit write permission to list of valid users
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        # Require SSL connection for password protection
        SSLRequireSSL

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Authorization Realm"
        AuthUserFile /path/to/passwdfile
        Require valid-user
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

I get the following error message when restarting http:

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:
Unknown DAV provider: svn
```

I have triple checked that I have the `mod_dav_svn` package already installed:

```
Package mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-10.el6_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Is my config wrong or are there other packages I need to set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that module mod_dav_svn is not loaded. Check you subversion.conf there should be uncommented the following line

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
```